# Create XML Hyperlink Download Link Dynamically

Tags: javascript, xml

I've got an xmlDoc which I'm creating and modifying dynamically with the following code:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
var parser = new DOMParser();

fileReader.onloadend = function(){
        var xmlData = fileReader.result;
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData,"text/xml");
    };
```

Later I output this to a textarea:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("resultTextArea");
var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
textArea.value = xmlText;
```

But I'd like to dynamically build the `.xml` file and offer it as a hyperlink download (right click and save as). Is this possible with HTML and Javascript (think it might not be due to security implications)?

ps. I'm trying to avoid external libraries (jQuery) but could use *if it's an absolute must*.

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Answer (score 0):

You can build the XML file by creating a `File` object in JavaScript:

```
var file = new File([xmlText], "filename.xml", {type: "application/xml"});
```

To offer this file with a link, you can create a `Data URI` from it.
Assuming, the variable `myButton` would be an `<a>` element, the code would look like this:

```
var reader  = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    myButton.href = reader.result;
}, false);

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

---

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL